# Transitive grunt plugin dependencies?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a grunt plugin called `snorky` that depends on the `grunt-compass` task. When someone types `npm install git://path/to/snorky`, I want the `grunt-compass` task to be installed automatically.

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "snorky",
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-compass": "~0.3.8"
  }
}
```

**tasks.snorky.js**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-compass');

  // ...

}
```

However, when I npm install snorky from another project, then try to run `grunt snorky`, I get an error:

```
user.name:~/other/proj [git: my-branch] $ grunt snorky
>> Local Npm module "grunt-compass" not found. Is it installed?
```

What is the right way to do this? I'm skeptical that it's necessary to `npm install grunt-compass` from the project that's using snorky.

Comment: What version of grunt are you using?

Answer (score 1):

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-compass

That package says it is deprecated for grunt 0.4 and its travisci build is failing.

Under installation instruction it also says

1. **Install this grunt plugin next to your project's grunt.js gruntfile with: `npm install grunt-compass`.**

So maybe it is just necessary to run the npm install.

### You should try using [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass)

It's builds are succeeding and its meant for use with 0.4